# R:How to intersect list of dataframes and specifc column

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am trying to find all matching values in a specific column, in a list of data.frames. However, I keep getting a returned value of `character(0)`.

I have tried the following:
Simple subset (very time consuming) -> e.g. dat[[i]][[i]]
lapply w/ Reduce and intersect (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143518/intersecting-a-list-of-data-frames-in-r)

```r
LocA<-data.frame(obs.date=c("2018-01-10","2018-01-14","2018-01-20),
obs.count=c(2,0,1))
LocB<-data.frame(obs.date=c("2018-01-09","2018-01-14","2018-01-20),
obs.count=c(0,3,5))
LocC<-data.frame(obs.date=c("2018-01-12","2018-01-14","2018-01-19"),
obs.count=c(2,0,1))
LocD<-data.frame(obs.date=c("2018-01-11","2018-01-16","2018-01-21"),
obs.count=c(2,0,1))

dfList<-list(LocA,LocB,LocC,LocD)

##List of all dates 

lapply(dfList,'[[',1)
[1]"2018-01-10" "2018-01-14" "2018-01-20" "2018-01-09"...
```

Attempts (failure)

```r
>Reduce(intersect,lapply(dfList,'[[',1))
character (0)
```

I expect the output of this function to be an output identifying the data.frames that share a common date.

*Extra smiles if someone know how to identify shared dates and mutate in to a single data frame where..Col1 = dataframe name, Col2=obs.date,Col3 = obs.count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first merge all the data frames so you only have one:

```
a <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE), dfList)
```

Or you can merge them like this:

```
a <-rbind(LocA,LocB,LocC,LocD)
```

Afterwards, you can extract all the duplicates:

```
b <- a[duplicated(a$obs.date), ]
```

Or if you want to keep all the unique ones and keep the duplicates:

```
c <- a[!duplicated(a$obs.date), ]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Any idea if I can format the returned dataframe to list the same info, but where each column is a location? Like...

date            | LocA | LocB | LocC ...
01-01-2018     2         0          1

I am would like to run Poisson against the counts to see relations (if any)

Comment: Nice to hear that I could help! No, sadly I don't know a handy solution to this. But you can try and add a variable called Location like this `Location = c("D", "D", "D")`. Then you can see the Locations. And then there is definitely a way to formate this into the data frame you want :)

Comment: `LocA<-data.frame(obs.date=c("2018-01-10","2018-01-14","2018-01-20"),
obs.count=c(2,0,1),  Location = c("A", "A", "A"))
LocB<-data.frame(obs.date=c("2018-01-09","2018-01-14","2018-01-20"),
                 obs.count=c(0,3,5),  Location = c("B", "B", "B"))
LocC<-data.frame(obs.date=c("2018-01-12","2018-01-14","2018-01-19"),
                 obs.count=c(2,0,1),  Location = c("C", "C", "C"))

LocD<-data.frame(obs.date=c("2018-01-11","2018-01-16","2018-01-21"),
                 obs.count=c(2,0,1), Location = c("D", "D", "D"))`

Answer (score 0):

If by "intersect" you mean doing an "inner join" or "merging" with a specific column as key, then -- you want to use `dplyr::inner_join` or `merge`.

First, between two data.frames:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(LocA, LocB, by='obs.date')
# 2 rows
inner_join(LocC, LocD, by='obs.date')
# zero rows
```

So, not infinite merging.

## Stack, then count

We'll combine the data first, then count the occurences. Notice the use of the `.id`-argument to track where the row originated.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(dfList, .id = 'id') %>%
  add_count(obs.date) %>% 
  filter(n > 1)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  id    obs.date   obs.count     n
  <chr> <chr>          <dbl> <int>
1 1     2018-01-14         0     3
2 1     2018-01-20         1     2
3 2     2018-01-14         3     3
4 2     2018-01-20         5     2
5 3     2018-01-14         0     3
```